# How to assign the roots of transcendental equation into an equation

Tags: equation-solving

Firstly, I'm going to find the roots of transcendental equation then assign the roots into an equation to solve it. However, I don't know how to ask Mathematica to assign the roots into the equation.

```
β = {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100};k=0.5;

eqn = Table[α[n]*BesselJ[1, α[n]] == BesselJ[0, α[n]] *β[[n]], {n, 1, 5}];
roots = Table[FindRoot[eqn[[n]], {α[n], 1}], {n, 1, 5}]
```

The output which are the roots of given transcendental equation:
[image]

`a1` is the equation that I need to assign the roots then I want to get the summation of `a1`. This is where I stuck because I don't know how to ask Mathematica to assign the roots that I got previously into equation `a1` then find the summation of `a1` as in the table below.

```
a1 = (BesselJ[0, k α[n]]^2 + BesselJ[1, k α[n]]^2) BesselY[1, k α[n]]^2;

find[m_] := Sum[a1, {n, 1}]

lst = Join[{{"β", "α[n]", "a1"}},Table[{β[[n]], roots[[n, 1, 2]], find[n]}, {n, 1, 5}]];
Grid[lst, Dividers -> All]
```

This table below is what I expected to get however for the summation of `a1` I'm not able to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors. Please copy and paste it into a notebook and see for yourself. In the definition of `find[m_]` the variable `m` does not appear on the right hand side. The question is also not very clear. Are you familiar with `/.`? See [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html) for example.

Comment: Hi. My bad, I already corrected the syntax error and tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you compute `roots`, you don't make any assignments to `α[n]`. That means that, if it just sees `α[n]` by itself, Mathematica doesn't know anything about which `α[n]` gets assigned to which value—so `a1` and in turn `find` can't use those values. All of the information regarding the assignment of `α[n]` to values is in `roots`.

What I would do is actually just make `a1` a function (note: it's not an equation!) taking in some argument alpha, then map it across your list of values, and `Accumulate` (which is the list of partial sums of the given list).

```
Clear[a1];
a1[α_] := (BesselJ[0, k α]^2 + BesselJ[1, k α]^2) BesselY[1, k α]^2

listOfAlphaSums = Accumulate[a1 /@ roots[[All,1,2]]]

lst = Join[{{"\[Beta]", "\[Alpha][n]", "a1"}}, 
   Transpose[{\[Beta], roots[[All, 1, 2]], listOfAlphaSums}]];

Grid[lst, Dividers -> All]
```

Note the switch to `Transpose`, since they're all lists now, and this has the same effect.

In the above, we follow your approach of using `Part` (`[[ ... ]]`) to extract the values on the rhs's. But as an aside, to use rules in more generality, check out `/.` (`ReplaceAll`). If you use `/.` with a list of rules, it will produce a single outcome. However, if you use it with a *list* of list of rules, like `roots`, it will produce a list of outcomes, one for each list of rules in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

α[β_?NumericQ] := Module[{a},
  a /. FindRoot[a*BesselJ[1, a] == BesselJ[0, a] β, {a, 1}]]

β = 10^Range[-2, 2];

α /@ β

(* {0.141245, 0.441682, 1.25578, 2.1795, 2.3809} *)

Show[
 LogLinearPlot[α[b], {b, 0.01, 100},
  PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[{#, α[#]} & /@ β,
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}],
 AxesOrigin -> {Log[8*^-3], 0}]
```

[image]